# Ruby on Rails - How to add a second route for the same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this route:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

A post can be a "User Message" showed at:
/posts

A post can be a "News" showed at:
/news

How can I create the "/news" url inside the routes.rb file and pass a param for know inside the post controller the type of post I want?

Comment: If you need to handle user posts and news differently, then maybe they shouldn't be in different controllers? You can extract the common logic into a service object or something, and call that from both controllers.

Comment: But @SergioTulentsev that won't the author shoehorn the entire application in a single controller!

Comment: "shouldn't" -> "should". Missed that one while rewording my comment a few times :)

Answer (score 0):

This way you can declare routes which can not be declared using `resources`.

```rb
get '/news' => 'posts#index', as: :news
```